# Vectorize MATLAB code

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Let's say we have three m-by-n matrices of equal size: `A`, `B`, `C`.

Every column in `C` represents a time series.
`A` is the running maximum (over a fixed window length) of each time series in `C`.
`B` is the running minimum (over a fixed window length) of each time series in `C`.

Is there a way to determine `T` in a vectorized way?

```
[nrows, ncols] = size(A);
T = zeros(nrows, ncols);
for row = 2:nrows                           %loop over the rows (except row #1).
    for col = 1:ncols                       %loop over the columns.
        if     C(row, col) > A(row-1, col)
            T(row, col) =  1;
        elseif C(row, col) < B(row-1, col)
            T(row, col) = -1;
        else
            T(row, col) = T(row-1, col);
        end
    end
end
```

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
T = zeros(m, n);
T(C > circshift(A,1)) =  1;
T(C < circshift(B,1)) = -1;
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what `T` is expected to be? Finding it a bit hard to follow the code... can you also provide example input matrices?

Comment: @rayryeng I edited the question and changed the loop index variable names from `m` to `row` and from `n` to `col`. I hope that makes things clearer. I'm still trying to come up with a good example of what *T* should look like.

Comment: I'll work out the code myself and see if I can make sense of it.

Comment: @rayryeng For better understanding I just removed one unnecessary variable. So now there are only three input matrices left: `A`, `B`, and `C`.
I also added a description w.r.t. what these matrices represent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the trouble was the dependency with the ELSE part of the conditional statement. So, after a long mental work-out, here's a way I summed up to vectorize the *hell-outta* everything.

Now, this approach is based on mapping. We get column-wise runs or islands of `1s` corresponding to the `2D` mask for the `ELSE` part and assign them the same tags. Then, we go to the `start-1` along each column of each such run and store that value. Finally, indexing into each such `start-1` with those tagged numbers, which would work as mapping indices would give us all the elements that are to be set in the new output.

Here's the implementation to fulfill all those aspirations -

```
%// Store sizes
[m1,n1] = size(A);

%// Masks corresponding to three conditions
mask1 = C(2:nrows,:) > A(1:nrows-1,:);
mask2 = C(2:nrows,:) < B(1:nrows-1,:);
mask3 = ~(mask1 | mask2);

%// All but mask3 set values as output
out = [zeros(1,n1) ; mask1 + (-1*(~mask1 & mask2))];

%// Proceed if any element in mask3 is set
if any(mask3(:))

    %// Row vectors for appending onto matrices for matching up sizes
    mask_appd = false(1,n1);
    row_appd = zeros(1,n1);

    %// Get 2D mapped indices
    df = diff([mask_appd ; mask3],[],1)==1;
    cdf = cumsum(df,1);

    offset = cumsum([0 max(cdf(:,1:end-1),[],1)]);
    map_idx = bsxfun(@plus,cdf,offset);
    map_idx(map_idx==0) = 1;

    %// Extract the values to be used for setting into new places
    A1 = out([df ; false(1,n1)]);

    %// Map with the indices obtained earlier and set at places from mask3
    newval = [row_appd ; A1(map_idx)];
    mask3_appd = [mask_appd ; mask3];
    out(mask3_appd) = newval(mask3_appd);

end
```

Comment: Dear God. I don't know how the hell you figured that out. +1.

Comment: @rayryeng Couple hours of mental torture precisely ;)

Comment: Holy cow, that's incredible!! +1

Comment: @bluebox Appreciate the compliment there, was some work! :D

Answer (score 2):

Doing this vectorized is rather difficult because the current row's output depends on the previous row's output.  Doing vectorized operations usually means that each element should stand out on its own using some relationship that is independent of the other elements that surround it.

I don't have any input on how you would achieve this without a `for` loop but I can help you reduce your operations down to one instead of two.  You can do the assignment vectorized per row, but I can't see how you'd do it all in one shot.

As such, try something like this instead:

```
[nrows, ncols] = size(A);
T = zeros(nrows, ncols);
for row = 2:nrows                           
    out = T(row-1,:); %// Change - Make a copy of the previous row
    out(C(row,:) > A(row-1,:)) = 1; %// Set those elements of C 
                                    %// in the current row that are larger
                                    %// than the previous row of A to 1
    out(C(row,:) < B(row-1,:)) = -1; %// Same logic but for B now and it's 
                                     %// less than and the value is -1 instead
    T(row,:) = out; %// Assign to the output
end
```

I'm currently figuring out how to do this with any loops whatsoever. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful! +1